# How to remove specific strings from a list

Tags: python

From the following list how can I remove elements ending with Text.

My expected result  is `a=['1,2,3,4']`

My List is  `a=['1,2,3,4,5Text,6Text']`

Should i use endswith to go about this problem?

Comment: Why does your list contain a single string with comma-separated values in it, and why do you want a list with a single string in it as output instead of something more usable? Would you prefer a result of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: Do you want to remove the items that literally end in `Text`, or do you want something more general, such as removing items with non-numeric characters in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.endswith` to filter out such items:

```
>>> a = ['1,2,3,4,5Text,6Text']
>>> [','.join(x for x in a[0].split(',') if not x.endswith('Text'))]
['1,2,3,4']
```

Here `str.split` splits the string at `','` and returns a list:

```
>>> a[0].split(',')
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5Text', '6Text']
```

Now filter out items from this list and then join them back using `str.join`.

Comment: Yes i need the resultant in an array

Answer (score 4):

Split on commas, then filter on strings that are only digits:

```
a = [','.join(v for v in a[0].split(',') if v.isdigit())]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a=['1,2,3,4,5Text,6Text']
>>> [','.join(v for v in a[0].split(',') if v.isdigit())]
['1,2,3,4']
```

It *looks* as if you really wanted to work with lists of more than one element though, at which point you could just filter:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5Text', '6Text']
a = filter(str.isdigit, a)
```

or, using a list comprehension (more suitable for Python 3 too):

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5Text', '6Text']
a = [v for v in a if v.isdigit()]
```

Comment: `'5'` and `'6'` don't appear in the OP's expected output.

Comment: @user2357112: ah, I was being too clever by half.

Answer (score 0):

try this. This works with every text you have in the end.

```
a=['1,2,3,4,5Text,6Text']
a = a[0].split(',')

li = []
for v in a:
    try : li.append(int(v))
    except : pass

print li
```