# Remove elments from unicode data

Tags: python

How to split and print the contents of the unicode string.I have to remove elments ending with `div` from the following list.Expected list is a=[u'1,2,3,4,5']

I had earlier asked [How to remove specific strings from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970202/how-to-remove-specific-strings-from-a-list)

```
      a=[u'1,2,3,4,5,6div,7div']
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: This is nearly identical to your previous question. The only differences are that the string is now unicode, and the text is `div` instead of `Text`. Try to generalize the answers provided for your previous question before asking another.

Comment: Also, again, I would like to ask whether it really makes sense to use a 1-element list with a string containing comma-separated values. You're not getting anything useful from having a list at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this,

```
>>> a=[u'1,2,3,4,5,6div,7div']
>>> [ item for item in a[0].split(',') if item.isdigit()]
[u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
splitter = [item for item in a[0].split(',') if not item.endswith('div')]
```

For more detailed infos:

[1] http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

[2]  http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk