# Set list to None in list comprehension

Tags: python, list

In the following code  any element after splitting does end with 'div' then it should be the resultant of new list but right now i get  b = [''] .My question is how to make the list empty b=[]

```
a=['1div,2div,3div,4div,5div']

b= [','.join(i for i in a[0].split(',') if not a.endswith('div'))]
```

Comment: Why are you working with a list of just one string? You cannot do what you want in just one statement, because you are always producing a string value with the `','.join()` here.

Comment: You have a list of one element... you want to be doing the operations on that element - not the list itself...

Comment: @Rajeev lists don't have `a.endswith('div')` method.

Comment: Also, obviously you don't want the list to be None but empty.

Comment: I see you're the same guy who asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970202/how-to-remove-specific-strings-from-a-list) question. Why are you *still* working with this nonsense data representation? Why do you have code that converts your data from a sensible list of items to the weird, giant string?

Comment: @user2357112: I agree its non sense but still have to fix what has to be fixed :)

Comment: @Rajeev: then 'break' the data at the end points, fix when it comes in. In between those two points, work with something sane.

Comment: Sure..The UI sends the div with their ids and this was the scenario here..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the errors in your code, you can do:

```
result = [','.join(i for i in a[0].split(',') if not i.endswith('div'))]
b = result if result[0] else []
#or
result = ','.join(i for i in a[0].split(',') if not i.endswith('div'))
b = [result] if result else []
```

And using just a one element list makes no sense here.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
filter(lambda x: not x.endswith('div'), a[0].split(","))
```